# Visual Studio 2022 preview MAUI deployment errors to Android devices

Tags: android, maui

The title line says it all.

I get an error when I try debugging on Android devices(either local or emulator).  I don't know where to look for the error.  Windows works fine.

I do see this message sometimes:

*DEP1700: The recipe file "C:...\net7.0-android\LogGate.build.appxrecipe" does not exist. You may need to build your project.  LogGate*

After restarting VS and rebuilding I did get it to work, but is this the correct solution?

Comment: This is very unclear.  You get an occasional error that goes away after restarting?  Or you consistently get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Configuration Manager, and make sure both **Build** and **Deploy** are checked.

(Right click on the solution > Configuration Manager)